# vcftools - installing on MAC

Tags: bioinformatics, vcftools

I'm trying to install vcftools on mac. Looking at previous posts on this issue, I made sure I've got Mac OS X developer tools (http://www.cnet.com/how-to/install-command-line-developer-tools-in-os-x/). I followed the procedure recommended in the official documantion (https://vcftools.github.io/examples.html). When I run from the command line:

> ./configure.ac

I get the following errors:

> ./configure.ac: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `[2.63]'
>   ./configure.ac: line 4:`AC_PREREQ([2.63])'

If I try:

> ./configure

It says:

> -bash: ./configure: No such file or directory

as indeed there in no ./configure when I inspect the contents with:

> ls

Can anyone point out where I am doing wrong. I've tried resources such as 'homebrew' but I didn't help.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: How did you download it?  I pulled the latest tar file from https://github.com/vcftools/vcftools/releases, downloaded it and I see the `configure` script in there.

Answer (score -1):

you can download it from

```
git clone https://github.com/vcftools/vcftools.git
cd vcftools
```

you will need to install autoconf, pkg-config, libtools, automake, and zlib.

run

```
./autogen.sh
```

then

```
./configure
```

follow the instructions here: https://github.com/vcftools/vcftools

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issue. Basically you need to install automake. This can be done using

```
brew install automake
```

Check this out https://www.biostars.org/p/306802/

Comment: I don't understand the downvote...this is something I tried and it works. I was facing the same problem as the OP